# How can I update the comments without refreshing it?

Tags: vue.js, axios, lifecycle

First, I'm using vuex and axios.

- store: commentService.js
- components:

  - CommentBox.vue (Top components)
  - CommentEnter.vue (Sub components)

This is the logic of the code I wrote.

In the store called commentService.js, there are mutations called `commentUpdate`.
And There are actions called `postComment` and `getComment`.

At this time, In the component called `CommentBox` dispatches `getComment` with `async created()`.

Then, in `getComment`, `commentUpdate` is commited and executed.

`CommentUpdate` creates an array of comments inquired by `getComment` and stores them in a state called `commentList`.

Then I'll get a commentList with "computed".

`CommentEnter`, a sub-component, uses the `commentList` registered as compounded in the `CommentBox` as a prop.

The code below is commentService.js.

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: () => ({
    comment:'',
    commentList: []
  }),
  mutations: {
    commentUpdate(state, payload) {
      Object.keys(payload).forEach(key => {
        state[key] = payload[key]
      })
    }
  },
  actions: {
    postComment(state, payload) {
      const {id} = payload
      axios.post(`http://??.???.???.???:????/api/books/${id}/comments`, {
        comment: this.state.comment,
        starRate: this.state.starRate
      }, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ` + localStorage.getItem('user-token')
        }
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        this.state.comment = ''
        this.state.starRate = ''
       )
      .catch((err) => {
        alert('댓글은 한 책당 한 번만 작성할 수 있습니다.')
        console.log(err)
        this.state.comment = ''
        this.state.starRate = ''
      })
    },
    async getComment({commit}, payload) {
      const {id} = payload
      axios.get(`http://??.???.???.???:????/api/books/${id}/comments`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        const { comment } = res.data.commentMap
        commit('commentUpdate', {
          commentList: comment
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        commit('commentUpdate', {
          commentList: {}
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The code below is CommentBox.vue

```js
  computed: {
    commentList() {
      return this.$store.state.commentService.commentList
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async newComment() {
      if(this.$store.state.loginService.UserInfoObj.id === '') {
        alert('로그인 후 이용할 수 있습니다.')
        return
      }
      this.$store.dispatch('commentService/postComment', {
        id: this.$route.params.id,
        comment: this.$store.state.comment,
        starRate: this.$store.state.starRate
      })
    }
  },
  async created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('commentService/getComment', {
      id: this.$route.params.id
    })
  }
```

The code below is CommentEnter.vue

```js
  created() {
    this.userComment = this.comment
  },
  props: {
    comment: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    }
  },
```

I asked for a lot of advice.

There were many comments asking for an axios get request after the axios post request was successful.

In fact, I requested an axios get within `.then()` of the axios post, and the network tab confirmed that the get request occurred normally after the post request.

But it's still not seen immediately when I register a new comment.

I can only see new comments when I refresh it.

How can I make a new comment appear on the screen right away when I register it?

Comment: Try to remove async/await pairs.

Comment: which async/await pairs?
all of it?

Comment: Yes. I suggest either using promise-based or async/await syntax. Mixing them is clumsy.

Comment: Ok, Then after registering the comments, how can I see the registered comments without refreshing?

Comment: Could you post the new code such that we can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just call `getComment` when `postComment` is finished?

```js
methods: {
    async newComment() {
      if(this.$store.state.loginService.UserInfoObj.id === '') {
        alert('로그인 후 이용할 수 있습니다.')
        return
      }
      this.$store.dispatch('commentService/postComment', {
        id: this.$route.params.id,
        comment: this.$store.state.comment,
        starRate: this.$store.state.starRate
      }).then(function() {
        this.$store.dispatch('commentService/getComment', {
          id: this.$route.params.id
        })
      })
    }
  },
}
```

Or since you're using `async`:

```js
methods: {
    async newComment() {
      if(this.$store.state.loginService.UserInfoObj.id === '') {
        alert('로그인 후 이용할 수 있습니다.')
        return
      }
      await this.$store.dispatch('commentService/postComment', {
        id: this.$route.params.id,
        comment: this.$store.state.comment,
        starRate: this.$store.state.starRate
      })
      this.$store.dispatch('commentService/getComment', {
        id: this.$route.params.id
      })
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work....

Comment: What _exactly_ does not work? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Both of them issue error messages.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$store')

Comment: In this part    ((( this.$store.dispatch('commentService/getComment', {
                    id: this.$route.params.id
                  }); )))

Comment: `await this.$store.dispatch('commentService/postComment')` works but `this.$store.dispatch('commentService/getComment'` doesn't? that sounds slightly weird

Comment: Please don't open new questions to the same problems. Instead, update your existing question when you want to add information.